# How can I pass part of an url to my controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, controller

I'm making a registration form where after filling in a form, users get an email with all the info they've submitted including a link where they can edit their registration. Example url: `localhost/registrationapp/edit/{id}`

I've been trying to pass part of the url to a controller, this is my route:

```
Route::get('/edit/{id}', [RegistrationappController::class, 'edit'])->with('id', $id);
```

And I got this function in my controller:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return 123;
        $registration= Registrationapp::find($id);
        return view('edit')->with('registration, $registration);
    }
```

The `return 123` part is just added to see if I can even get to the controller, but it doesn't reach the controller. Instead I'm getting this error when I go to a url (for example `localhost/registrationapp/edit/5`):

```
Undefined variable $id
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is `$id` supposed to be? where did you define that variable? ... route parameters are dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `->with('id', $id);`

**Note** : if you are using url : `localhost/registrationapp/edit/{id}` , make sure to include `registrationapp` in route :

```
Route::get('registrationapp/edit/{id}', [RegistrationappController::class, 'edit']);
```

Comment: After adding ``registrationapp/edit/{id}`` it worked, thanks a lot! To everyone reading this in the future, make sure to include the entire url in the rout. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you need to have your route just as `Route::get('/registrationapp/edit/{id}', [TestController::class, 'edit']);`.

Please feel free to look at my laravel 7 snippet here, https://phpsandbox.io/n/73314638-5fvdc. It demonstrates below:

```php
Route::get('/registrationapp/edit/{id}', [TestController::class, 'edit']);
```

Note, I borrowed the default `welcome.blade.php` file, and updated the default `/` route in `web.php`.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('welcome', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

Edit: You're right in [your comment reply from accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73314638/how-can-i-pass-part-of-an-url-to-my-controller-in-laravel/73314813#comment129475733_73314950), I missed a prefix to your example URL you shared, apologies about that. I've updated my answer here.